# Getting Mongo write error in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am trying to insert a new field like this, and I am getting a write error.
If I remove this line, the program works fine.

```
UserDetails.update({userId: Meteor.UserId()}, {$inc: {score: 5}});
```

Error trace is:

```
I20141107-12:55:38.278(5.5)? Exception in Mongo write: TypeError: object is not a function
I20141107-12:55:38.323(5.5)?     at packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:293
I20141107-12:55:38.323(5.5)?     at runWithEnvironment (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:108)
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you just have a typo. It should be `Meteor.userId()`

Reference: https://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Meteor-userId

UPDATE (11/9/14): It just dawned on me that you're using Meteor.userId() which gets the current user id from the Meteor.users collection. But it looks like you're trying to update the score for a user in a collection called UserDetails. The syntax to update a specific user id is this:

```
UserDetails.update("biwyMQCriR3KDFHod", {$inc: {score: 5} });
```

Where `"biwyMQCriR3KDFHod"` (with the double quotes) is the unique id value for that user.

I'm not sure how you're doing your update (perhaps you could share your code using http://meteorpad.com), but you might want to take a look at using Session.

Session References:

- http://meteortips.com/book/sessions/
- https://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/session

Comment: Isn't this exactly what the OP said he is using in his code?

Comment: The OP has a typo. The OP used an uppercase U in Meteor.UserId(). It should be lowercase u, Meteor.userId().

Comment: yes the user should start with lowercase letter,but the problem is not that,i tried directly userId value without using Meteor.userId() still i am getting the same error.

Comment: @user2808306 I updated my answer to show how to update a specific user by their unique id.